# DEPRECATION WARNING on save with ruby and active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am new to ruby and writing a small script that requires writing messages to a database log.

I am using ruby 1.9.3 with active_record but without rails. All select statements work fine, but my write to log function is returning the following error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `ID'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc.
```

my model looks like that

```
class ActLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ActLog"
  self.primary_key = "ID"
end
```

and my log function:

```
def log(level, message)
  level.upcase!
  line = ActLog.new
  line.level = level
  line.message = message
  line.module = 'script'
  line.date = Time.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  line.save
end
```

the `ID` field is an int auto_increment.

The log function will be called many times during the execution. Is that the best way to write to the log and why is the deprecation warning popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [the API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name=) and the methods you're using are current. I think you may need attr_accessor

```
class ActLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :id, :level, :message, :module, :date
  self.table_name = "ActLog"
  self.primary_key = "ID"
end

def log(level, message)
  attr = { :level   => level.upcase!,
           :message => message,
           :module  => 'script',
           :date    => Time.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") }
  ActLog.new(attr).save!
end
```

Comment: :id may or may not need to be changed to "ID".

Comment: also, module is a reserved keyword. try "module" if it complains.

Comment: your solution worked, module was not a problem. I tried just removing `self.primary_key` and it worked without the attr_accessor..

Answer (score 0):

I think your class should be as follows:

```
class ActLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ID'
  self.table_name = 'ActLog'
end
```

Out of curiosity, why the non-standard names?

Comment: the set_functions are also deprecated.. It is a log table I inherited, can't do much about it, other software is writing to the same table.