# Rails 3.2 - Writing arbitrary attributes warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DEPRECATION WARNING on save with ruby and active_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632438/deprecation-warning-on-save-with-ruby-and-active-record)

I have the following simple piece of code that assigns event type (which is a model) to my event model:

```
def event_type=(new_event_type)
  self.event_type_id = new_event_type.id
  write_attribute(:event_type, new_event_type)
end
```

It works fine, however after upgrading to Rails 3.2 I get the following message:

**You're trying to create an attribute `event_type'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use`attr_writer` etc.**

The warning is at "write_attribute" line.

Any suggestion why this warning is happening and what's the best way to address it would be appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: I've only seen that happen when you have forgotten to migrate your database. Have you ensured that the database is up to date?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell, I've checked the migrations and they are all up to date.  As for the possible duplicate question, I'm not 100% sure that what I need is the attr_accessor.  Would I need it for every single attribute on my model as described in the answer for that question?